# How to get state after useReducer's dispatch?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Is there any way to get updated state after dispatch?

Imagine that I'm trying to write some hook which gets state from context (where the value is the result of useReducer) dispatches action depending on state and returns back updated one:

```
const useHook = (state, dispatch) => {
    if (state.flag) {
        dispatch({
            type: `UNSET_FLAG`,
        })
    } else {
        dispatch({
            type: `SET_FLAG`,
        })
    }
}

const Foo = () => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useContext(MyContext);

    useHook(state, dispatch);

    return state.flag ? <Flagged /> : <Unflagged /> ;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any comments and ideas

P.S. for description purposes the example is just the first stupid thing from my head.